# To display result of form using Javascript in other php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

This is my `rat.php` file, that displays a question form of 8 questions. I use `onsubmit="getScore(this.form)` to refer to my Javascript code. My Javascript code is in the display file which is `ratResult.php`.

However, my display file only captures the answers chosen but not the percentage. There is no error shown, but the percentage is the thing that I most need.

```
<form method="POST" action="ratResult.php" onsubmit="getScore(this.form)">

                      <div id="form" style="text-align:left">
                      <br><h2>Please answer all questions</h2><br>
                      <?PHP print question(1); ?>
                      <br><input type = "radio" name = "rat1" value = "<?PHP print ansHigh(1); ?>"><?PHP print ansHigh(1); ?><br>
                      <input type = "radio" name = "rat1" value = "<?PHP print ansLow(1); ?>"><?PHP print ansLow(1); ?><br><br>
                      <?PHP print question(2); ?>
                      <br><input type = "radio" name = "rat2" value = "<?PHP print ansHigh(2); ?>"><?PHP print ansHigh(2); ?><br>
                      <input type = "radio" name = "rat2" value = "<?PHP print ansLow(2); ?>"><?PHP print ansLow(2); ?><br><br>
```

This is the section in file `ratResult.php` that displays all answers chosen and the percentage.

```
<div id="test" style="text-align:left">
                <?php


                if(empty($_POST)===false){

                $rat1 = $_POST['rat1'];
                $rat2 = $_POST['rat2'];
                $rat3 = $_POST['rat3'];
                $rat4 = $_POST['rat4'];
                $rat5 = $_POST['rat5'];
                $rat6 = $_POST['rat6'];
                $rat7 = $_POST['rat7'];
                $rat8 = $_POST['rat8'];

                echo "<h4>RAT</h4>";
                echo "Answer 1: ".$rat1."<br>";
                echo "Answer 2: ".$rat2."<br>";
                echo "Answer 3: ".$rat3."<br>";
                echo "Answer 4: ".$rat4."<br>";
                echo "Answer 5: ".$rat5."<br>";
                echo "Answer 6: ".$rat6."<br>";
                echo "Answer 7: ".$rat7."<br>";
                echo "Answer 8: ".$rat8."<br>";

                $insert = mysql_query('INSERT INTO ratresult(username,q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,dateTaken)VALUES("'.$loginSession.'","'.$rat1.'"
                ,"'.$rat2.'","'.$rat3.'","'.$rat4.'","'.$rat5.'","'.$rat6.'","'.$rat7.'","'.$rat8.'",now())') or die (mysql_error($insert));
                }
                else
                echo "error!";

                ?>
                Score = <input type=text size=15 name="percentage"><br>
                <hr /><a href=main.php>Back To Main Page </a>
```

This is the Java Script to calculate the percentage.

```js
<script>
   var numQues = 8;
   var numChoi = 2;
   var answers = new Array(8);
   answers[0] = "Yes";
   answers[1] = "Above 50 years old";
   answers[2] = "Below 12 years old";
   answers[3] = "Yes";
   answers[4] = "No";
   answers[5] = "Yes";
   answers[6] = "Yes";
   answers[7] = "Above 50 years old";
   function getScore(form) {
   var score = 0;
   var currElt;
   var currSelection;
   for (i=0; i<numQues; i++) {
    currElt = i*numChoi;
    for (j=0; j<numChoi; j++) {
      currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
      if (currSelection.checked) {
        if (currSelection.value == answers[i]) {
          score++;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  score = Math.round(score/numQues*100);
  form.percentage.value = score + "%";
  var correctAnswers = "";
  for (i=1; i<=numQues; i++) {
    correctAnswers += i + ". " + answers[i-1] + "\r\n";
  }
  form.solutions.value = correctAnswers;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is your browser's console giving you a JavaScript error?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Don't use connecting words like 'Basically'. Clean up sentence structure. Mind your tenses. Don't include extraneous information (knowing that you googled does not help figure out what your problem is). Format code so it stands out clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing anything in your JavaScript that explicitly says where the percentage has to go. You have a form field with the name "percentage" but it has no ID, and JavaScript will pick up on IDs rather than names. So I'd redefine that as:

```
<input type=text size=15 name="percentage" id="percentage">
```

Then in your JavaScript you could spell out where the result has to go:

```
document.getElementById("percentage").value = score + "%";
```

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to tell the flow of the execution of the code with what you have provided, but I suspect that you may be adding the script block before the form is ever loaded in the DOM. Make sure the script block is inside the body tag, at the end of the page after the html for the form.